# Camera in android for resultCode

Tags: android, android-camera

I am getting `resultCode` -1 when I captured an image using `Intent` in android.

**Here is my button click code.**

```
   public void capture(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        imageFile = new File(
                Environment.
                        getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                                (Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) ,
                "Test"
                );
        Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT , imageUri);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY , 1);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 3);
    }
```

**Here is my ActivityResult method of my app.....**

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == 3)
        {
            Log.i("Result code is : \t" , resultCode+"");
            switch (resultCode)
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK :
                    if (imageFile.exists())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(this , "File saved at \n"+imageFile.getAbsolutePath() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(this , "Error while capturing" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    break;

                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED :

                    break;

                default :
                    Toast.makeText(this , "Some error" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Please help me I am getting Result code -1....
Anyone please help me....
I am new at android.....

Comment: `Activity.RESULT_OK = -1`

Comment: now i want to save it into gallery how i do????

Comment: That's a completely different question.

Comment: okkkk.... Thanks....

Comment: My imageFile is not exist according to my code can u tell me y????

Answer (score 2):

you are using intent to call an Activity and requesting result from the activity.

```
public void capture(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    imageFile = new File(
            Environment.
                    getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
                            (Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) ,
            "Test"
            );
    Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT , imageUri);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY , 1);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 3);
}
```

and on OnAcitvityResult just Use

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == 3)
    {
        Log.i("Result code is : \t" , resultCode+"");
        switch (resultCode)
        {
            case RESULT_OK :
                if (imageFile.exists())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this , "File saved at \n"+imageFile.getAbsolutePath() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this , "Error while capturing" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                break;

            case RESULT_CANCELED :

                break;

            default :
                Toast.makeText(this , "Some error" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

By Default the value of RESULT_OK and RESULT_CANCELLED are defined in ACIVITY Class.

In Acivity Class

```
 /** Standard activity result: operation canceled. */
    public static final int RESULT_CANCELED    = 0;
    /** Standard activity result: operation succeeded. */
    public static final int RESULT_OK           = -1;
    /** Start of user-defined activity results. */
    public static final int RESULT_FIRST_USER   = 1;
```

That's why you are getting RESULT_OK = -1;